# How can I view the list of the questions that were the most recently reopened on a given SE site?

Tags: support, reopened-questions

I wonder if there is a way to view the list of the questions that were the most recently reopened on a given SE site.

Answer (score 8):

There's an overview in the [moderator tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=close&daterange=last30days) - you need 10k reputation to access those, not a diamond:

[image]

Other than that, your best bet is probably SEDE: [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1814405) lists the most recently reopened questions since the last refresh (every Sunday morning UTC).

[image]

There is no way to get real-time information via a [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) call - post history isn't exposed this way.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the "Recently Reopened" list in the 10k tools (https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=Close&daterange=last30days), otherwise you're stuck with guessing using the homepage (reopens bump the question) or [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1794046/recently-closed-reopened-questions) (only updated on Sundays).